# PHP find relevance

Tags: php, lucene, sphinx

Say I have a collection of 100,000 articles across 10 different topics. I don't know which articles actually belong to which topic but I have the entire news article (can analyze them for keywords). I would like to group these articles according to their topics. Any idea how I would do that? Any engine (sphinx, lucene) is ok.

Comment: This sounds like something that Google probably employs 300 top-notch people for in the Google News department... Not sure whether freely available solutions to categorize articles exist, especially in the PHP world. But you never know; interested to see what comes up.

Comment: I'm guessing this is the kind of thing that an academic paper is written on :)

Comment: First you need to define a criteria on which you say, that article X belongs to the topic Y. Is that just "words A, B, C, connected to topic Y all exist in the article X"?

Answer (score 2):

In term of machine learning/data mining, we called these kind of problems as the **classification problem**. The easiest approach is to use past data for future prediction, i.e. statistical oriented: 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_classification, in which you can start by using the **Naive Bayes classifier** (commonly used in spam detection)

I would suggest you to read this book (Although written for Python): Programming Collective Intelligence ([http://www.amazon.com/Programming-Collective-Intelligence-Building-Applications/dp/0596529325](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596529325)), they have a good example.

Answer (score 2):

Well an apache project providing maschine learning libraries is **Mahout**. Its features include the possibility of:

> [...] Clustering takes e.g. text documents and groups them into groups of topically related documents. Classification learns from exisiting categorized documents what documents of a specific category look like and is able to assign unlabelled documents to the (hopefully) correct category. [...]

You can find Mahout under http://mahout.apache.org/

Although I have never used Mahout, just considered it ;-), it always seemd to require a decent amount of theoretical knowledge. So if you plan to spend some time on the issue, Mahout would probably be a good starting point, especially since its well documented. But don't expect it to be easy ;-)

Comment: Ui, I totally forgot to mention another alternative. If you seek something like mahout, but being easier to implement try out Bobo-Browse: http://sna-projects.com/bobo/

Actually I believe Bobo-Browse could do an excellent job in your case.

Comment: hi friend i need help in sphinx .I am new to Sphinx .how configure the sphinx in wamp sever in local host.

Answer (score 1):

Dirt simple way to create a classifier:

Hand read and bucket N example documents from the 100K into each one of your 10 topics.  Generally, the more example documents the better.

Create a Lucene/Sphinx index with 10 documents corresponding to each topic.  Each document will contain all of the example documents for that topic concatenated together.

To classify a document, submit that document as a query by making every word an OR term.  You'll almost always get all 10 results back.  Lucene/Sphinx will assign a score to each result, which you can interpret as the document's "similarity" to each topic.

Might not be super-accurate, but it's easy if you don't want to go through the trouble of training a real Naive Bayes classifier.  If you want to go that route you can Google for WEKA or MALLET, two good machine learning libraries.

Answer (score 1):

Excerpt from Chapter 7 of "Algorithms of the Intelligent Web" (Manning 2009):

"In other words, we’ll discuss the adoption of our algorithms in the context of a hypothetical
web application. In particular, our example refers to a news portal, which is inspired by the Google News website."

So, the content of Chapter 7 from that book should provide you with code for, and an understanding of, the problem that you are trying to solve.

Answer (score 0):

you could use sphinix to search for all the articles for all the 10 different topics and then set a threshold as to the number of matches that what make an article linked to a particular topic, and so on

Comment: The thing is, I don't know what topic it's going to be. It's dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend the book "Algorithms of the Intelligent Web" by Haralambos Marmanis and Dmitry Babenko. There's a chapter on how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't it is possible to completely automate this, but you could do most of it. The problem is where would the topics come from?

Extract a list of the most non-common words and phrases from each article and use those as tags.

Then I would make a list of Topics and assign words and phrases which would fall within that topic and then match that to the tags. The problem is that you might get more than one topic per article.

Perhaps the best way would be to use some form of Bayesian classifiers to determine which topic best describes the article. It will require that you train the system initially.

This sort of technique is used on determining if an email is SPAM or not.

This [article might](http://bytes.com/topic/php/answers/659405-simple-bayesian-classifier) be of some help